# How to fix a workspace that has been opened with "Run as Administrator" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, privileges

I opened Eclipse IDE with the "Run As Administrator" one day to do updates and install new software.  Then I forgot, and continued to work on my project.  Now, I can't work in that workspace unless I run Eclipse IDE with "Run As Administrator" which I would prefer not to do. Any suggestions on fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit access rights of the workspace dir and give full access right to your user.

Comment: Had to go into the advanced security options to ensure that all children gained the new permissions as well.